# Different Volume settings for Different players

Tags: iphone, mpmusicplayercontroller

I am implementing a audio based application. In my application I need to play the songs from my internal iPod application and application sounds simultaniously. I used 2 players , one  with avaudio and another one with MPMusicPlayer. But my problem is I need to input 2 different volume levels for these 2 different players. When I try to do it it is changing both players volume.

Can you guys please help me on this?

Thank you,
Sekhar.

Comment: I've answered a similar question recently. Take a look: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6867112/independent-volume-control-of-avaudioplayer-and-mpmusicplayercontroller-in-ios-ap/6871811#6871811