# Background iPod music Volume mixed with sound effects

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, background-music

What would the best method be for mixing background iPod music with sound effects?  The sound effects need to be adjustable and sometimes much louder than the background music.  When I use `MPMusicPlayerController` the volume is system-wide and reduces the effects volume as well.  I have been reading about `AVPlayer` and `AVAudipPlayer` but can't seem to locate a viable solution.

Any help and suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why do you think AVAudioPlayer isnt a viable solution? It sounds like it to me.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Have you looked at AVAudioSession Categories? I think that could help you with your problem. [The docs at Apple.](http://developer.apple.com/library/IOS/#documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVAudioSession_ClassReference/Reference/Reference.html)

Comment: This is a comment, not an answer

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you cannot play much louder sound over iPod music library because as you wrote iPod music use system volume. Unless the music files in your iPod library is compressed with very low volume.

Cocos 2D framework integrates very nice way how to mix-up more sound sources, but again it uses AVAudioPlayer for background music and Open AL for other sounds.

Comment: That is [how I figured to do it as well](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14881451/how-to-play-tracks-from-ipod-music-library-with-different-volume-than-system-vol/16655350#16655350)