# how to add a volum controller for AVPlayer in ios?

Tags: ios, volume, avplayer

I have an audio player developed in ios using `AVPlayer`. What I want to do is add a volum controller for this. I know it is easily get the current volum level when we use `AVAudioPlayer`. But I have no idea how to get the volum from `AVPlayer`. Please show me the correct way to do this.

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Independent Volume control of AVAudioPlayer and MPMusicPlayerController in iOS App.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6867112/independent-volume-control-of-avaudioplayer-and-mpmusicplayercontroller-in-ios-a)

Comment: Im using `AVPlayer` not the `AVAudioPlayer`

Comment: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa1716/_index.html